# Why put questions on hold instead of deletion, but delete answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I answered a question with no spam or offtopics. However, my answer got downvoted two times and then deleted.

Why delete answers instead of keeping them downvoted, while “wrong” questions instead “put on hold”?

My concern is that you cannot do anything if a moderator is biased, there are no requirements to a better consensus as it seems and at least some time, which looks wrong

Comment: i mean... how'd you attract so much attention that 5 users decided the answer needed to be deleted?

Comment: Post a screenshot so other users can see what you are talking about. And a link to the question.

Comment: Your question seem to be based on a false premise. [Questions are deleted as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380316/how-soon-should-a-bad-question-be-deleted).

Comment: The answer to your question may be specific to what happened and the question you answered though.'no offtopics' can be wrong. People will wanna look at the specifics.

Comment: @Patrice I expect such reaction, considering worse as a priority. But the main problem is that anyone can see and read questions on hold, and make their own decisions, but deleted answers disappear, like they never existed. And this may happen because of single person opinion, which make sense to me only if this is spam..

Comment: @croll Deleted answers do not disappear. Those with rep over 10k can see deleted posts.

Comment: @Croll deleted content is visible, and deleted stuff gets restored when it makes sense. If your point is 'my answer should be restored' link to it and explain why. If your point is to discuss the broader 'how much power do we give mods', go on meta.stackexchange and formulate your question there, I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers that do not answer the question get removed.

Closed questions eventually get deleted by the system if there are no answers after about 2 weeks to allow for the question to be altered.

There is no similar grace period for answers in the StackExchange system, but answerers are free to post an altered answer.

Comment: In what way is this "politically motivated discrimination" ?

Comment: I said this because you deleted my answer (not just downvoted, DELETED!) simply on your own opinion about the topic.

Comment: That's a big freaking leap from "deleted" to "politically motivated discrimination". And quite the accusation to level.

Comment: I am not sure how you can guess was my answer “answering the question” or not, alone. Votes and downvoted are much better approach

Comment: If it is not politically motivated, you could restore it and let it lay low downvoted. That will remove any accusations

Comment: It's not a guess. It's a calculation: The question is "What are they not free? What do the SSL certificates cost?" and your answer was "the prices are so high (you concede that there must be a cost, but only in an allusion) because they are greedy" - that simply does not answer the question.

Comment: So, in your mind, I am guilty of "politically motivated discrimination" unless I do what you want? You can see how that is not the way to play this, right?

Comment: No, it is not because you won’t do that, but because I feel that opinion (like any answer is initially opinion before others see reaction...) is removed just because it considered 1. bad 2. opinion - by one person.

Comment: Please review my reasons. It's not about opinions. It is entirely that the opinion did not answer the question.

Comment: I never said they are greedy. My answer was much more neutral than such word. I tried to gather facts that without much reason, there is no need for commercial company to make ssl certs free. It was a clever attempt to answer a question with no really better answer. Well, because this topic was discussed already on other sites.

Comment: Okay, let it be as community best people see this. Even if they re alone in their decision to delete harmless texts.

Comment: You keep trying to reframe the situation as a harmless post that should stay up because it is harmless. That's not the criteria here. The criteria is solely "does it answer the question asked?". Even completely wrong answers are supposed to stay up (according to policy) if they answer the question. So this Meta question is similarly misplaced: you are asking a question based on a faulty assumption that questions stay up forever while answers get deleted. The answer to ***that*** is that you are wrong about questions. What are you hoping other people will see?

Comment: It would look much more convincing if answers with no spam or other critical violations existed for an hour before they get deleted so they would have a broader reaction of few more people at least. There are more reasons to this, but I can agree that my answer was not complete, but just because the question is wrong too. I am eager to see what will be the correct answer from someone else later. https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/435879?noredirect=1

Comment: @Croll - I'm not sure what you mean by critical violations, but generally if a post meets the guidance in [answer] then it is likely to stay. If it doesn't qualify as an answer it gets deleted. You can always improve it so it can be undeleted, but we don't want posts that don't meet requirements.